# How to develop applications for Symbian OS V2?

Tags: c++, qt, symbian, s60, carbide

I want to develop applications for the S60V2 Platform..As I am stuck with a nokia 6630 for a few days....
I couldn't find documentation for other versions of Symbian but not v2...

Here : 
http://www.developer.com/ws/other/article.php/3627401/Carbide-Your-Mobile-Application.htm
The program only shows the SDK for S60V3 and UIQ3 but not S60V2...
So the question is how do you program a basic " Hello World " App for Phone like Nokia 6630?

Any Help Will Be Appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the SDK for S60 2nd here:

http://www.developer.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/4a7149a5-95a5-4726-913a-3c6f21eb65a5/S60-SDK-0616-3.0-mr.html

Comment: Hey! Thanks! I got the SDK...any idea on how to go about programming with it ?
Is there any method to program using linux ? I would prefer linux...it doesn't matter much though...

Comment: No idea. I never got a symbian before s60v5.

Comment: You can use `gnupoc` on Linux.